# UIView in iOS 5 using Storyboards does not rotate content on iPad device rotation

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm just getting started with Storyboards and iOS 5.1.  The application I'm building uses a navigation controller as its root controller, and is designed to be used in landscape orientation (it's an in-house enterprise application).

I created a single view, which worked properly: The content rotates properly to stay "right side up" when the simulator changes orientation.

I then added a new view, and that one *doesn't* rotate at all; the content stays in portrait orientation (and thus is sideways) when the device rotates.

I've looked through the settings for the two UIViewControllers and UIViews, and can't see any difference between them.  Any thoughts as to where I should look?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all each UIViewController in the storyboard must have a class sosiated with it. Create a new class which inherits from UIViewController and then, in the storyboard, click on the uiviewcontroller, and at the bottom of that controller, click on the right box and in the class inspector, replace UIViewController with the name of the new class your created.

Then, make sure that in every view controller class that you create, you implement the method

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

Just make this deleate method to return YES in EVERY view controller to make sure that all their views rotate in any orientation. Have you done this?

Comment: I cannot believe I forgot that; too dazzled by the Storyboard hotness... Thank you!

Comment: Technically, you don't have to have a view controller subclass for ever scene, but it's usually the case that you do.

Comment: Note that if you're using Xcode 4.5 but deploying to iOS 5.x this method will not be auto-generated in the UIViewController subclasses anymore (as it's been obsoleted in iOS 6.x), so you'll have to manually add it to make things work under iOS 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

This has bothered me as well. My app rotated in iPad simulator but not on an actual iPad. Weird enough. I had an UITabBarController with three tabs. All three controllers hooked up to the tab bar did have the method shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation, but just two of them (5 steps later on drilling through navigation controller) didn't. I've added the method to those as well and now it rotates.

Just my 2¢.